# Passing double quotes to Jscript

Tags: html, syntax, javascript

`insertText` is java script that accepts two string paramters

I need to pass two strings

first parameter:

```
<img src="
```

second

```
 ">
```

I just cant figure out how to pass double quote as parameter

This works

```
<a onClick="insertText('<em>', '</em>'); return false;">Italic</a>
```

This does not

```
<a onClick="insertText('<img src=/"', '/">'); return false;">Image</a>
```

Prints `'); return false;">Image`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The escape character for JavaScript is `\`, not `/`. So try this:

```
<a onClick="insertText('<img src=\"', '\">'); return false;">Image</a>
```

Update:

The solution above doesn't work, because the double-quotes "belong" to the HTML and not to the JavaScript, so we can't escape them in the JavaScript code.

Use this instead:

```
<a onClick="insertText('<img src=\'', '\'>'); return false;">Image</a> // --> <img src='...'>
```

or

```
<a onClick='insertText("<img src=\"", "\">"); return false;'>Image</a> // --> <img src="...">
```

Since you are using jQuery, why don't you do it the jQuery way?

```
insertText = function(a, b) {
    // your insertText implementation...
};

$('a').click(function() {  // use the right selector, $('a') selects all anchor tags
    insertText('<img src="', '">');
});
```

With this solution you can avoid the problems with the quotes.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jcDMN/

Answer (score 3):

You want to use \ rather than /

Answer (score 2):

The Golden Rule for that is reversing the quotation which means I use the single quotation ' inside the double quotation " and vice versa.

Also, you should use the backslash symbole to espape a special character like ' and ".

For example,
the following commands should work as they apply the rules mentioned above...

```
<a onClick="insertText('<em>', '</em>'); return false;">Italic</a>
```

or

```
<a onClick='insertText("<em>", "</em>"); return false;'>Italic</a>
```

or

```
<a onClick="insertText('<img src=\"', '\">'); return false;">Image</a>
```

or

```
<a onClick='insertText("<img src=\'", "\'>"); return false;'>Image</a>
```

I hope this helps you ...

Comment: Actually this is the best answer to your question, not the Jquery or any other, just inverting the quotes will do the job

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape it.

`<a onClick="insertText('<img src=\"', '\">'); return false;">Image</a>`